# Magento displays same page inside the visible page when trying to send/receive data from another php

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to make a new functionality on a custom back-end module that I've created a few weeks ago. The new functionality consists in making a query in order to list in a 'select-option' some data from an specific customer. Then, when I select one of these options, I've made a script that what does is catch the option, send it with `GET` method to another .php, and then, the php makes something with the data selected and then makes an echo with whatever.

The code is the following (`data.phtml`):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function showPresu(str){
    if (str=="")
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    alert('nothing here');
    return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert('makes request');
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        alert('new object');
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","receiveselection.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

As you can notice I've written some alerts in order to make sure that the code enters inside the script.

The select/option is the following(`data.phtml`):

```
echo '<select name="presus" onchange="showPresu(this.value)">';
    for($n=1;$n<=$h; $n++){
        echo "<option value='$status_id[$n]'>$status_id[$n]";
    }
    echo "</select>";
```

$status_id[$x]: It's an array that contains some data that I've introduced at the beginning.

And the div where the final data has to be displayed is (`data.phtml`):

```
<div id="txtHint">
<b>result info will be listed here.</b>
</div>
```

And finally, the PHP that has to interact with the info that I send via method `GET` is (`receiveselection.php`, in the same folder as `data.phtml`. Notice that this PHP will be changed to another code, I mean, I will change the following code to make another query, but now for making tests it's OK):

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
echo $q;
?>
```

The only issue is, when I try to show the 'receiveselecton.php' in the div created to do so, instead of watching the result of 'receiveselection.php' it appears the same magento page where I was in the moment before (`data.phtml`), I mean, it appears the same page twice, one as 'normal' and the other inside the `div`.

Does anyone know how to call the `receiveselection.php` instead of creating another `data.phtml`?

EDIT: If I put this code outside magento it works, but inside it does not. So the problem maybe is some incoherence with magento that I don't know. Or if anyone knows a better way to do it, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried your code in my sustem it is working fine.. the problem i figured out is that the request you are sending is not able to reach to file receiveselection.php

solution to your problem is you can create a controller action for receiveselection.php
lets say receiveselectionAction change your code to this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","your_module/your_controller/receiveselection.php?q="+str,true);
```

Comment: sorry for the delay answering you. Thanks a lot for your answer, I was desperate. Thanks.